# having issues on getting data from from datePickerDialog on android and sending it to firebase real time database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in this app development and I am making an **APP** that takes input from user like name, date and time and by clicking on submit button the data is sent to firebase database but I got stuck on datePickerDialog I am having issues on getting data from datePickerDialog. I am getting value of name by get and set method by making other java file with name member.java and it was done, my name value is showing on firebase database tree but from datePicker side I got confused  idk what value should I get and set that value so that firebase database can have that value, having difficulty in getting data from datePickerDialog,

here is the code with two java files ;

MAIN-ACTIVITY-JAVA:

```
Public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText firstname ,todays_date;
    float start_time;
    Button btnsave;
    DatabaseReference reff;
    Member member;
    long maxid = 0;
    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    private Button dateButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                initDatePicker();
                dateButton = findViewById(R.id.datepickerbutton);
                dateButton.setText(getTodaysDate());

        firstname =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        todays_date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.todays_date);
        btnsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        member = new Member();

        reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");
        reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                    maxid = (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int date = Integer.parseInt(todays_date.getText().toString().trim());

                member.setToday_date(date);
                member.setName(firstname.getText().toString().trim());
                reff.child(String.valueOf(maxid+1)).setValue(member);
                firstname.getText().clear();
                todays_date.getText().clear();


                }
        });
    }

    private String getTodaysDate() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        month = month + 1;
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return makeDateString(day,month,year);
    }

    private void initDatePicker() {
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                month = month + 1;
                String date = makeDateString (day, month, year);
                dateButton.setText(date);
            }
        } ;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        int style = THEME_HOLO_LIGHT;

        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,style,dateSetListener , year , month,day);
    }

    private String makeDateString(int day , int month ,int year){
        return getMonthFormat(month) + " " + day + " " + year;
    }

    private String getMonthFormat(int month) {
        if (month == 1)
            return  "JAN";
        if (month == 2)
            return  "FEB";
        if (month == 3)
            return  "MAR";
        if (month == 4)
            return  "APR";
        if (month == 5)
            return  "MAY";
        if (month == 6)
            return  "JUN";
        if (month == 7)
            return  "JUL";
        if (month == 8)
            return  "AUG";
        if (month == 9)
            return  "SEP";
        if (month == 10)
            return  "OCT";
        if (month == 11)
            return  "NOV";
        if (month == 12)
            return  "DEc";
        return "JAN";
    }

    public void openDatePicker(View view) {
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

MEMBER.JAVA:

```
public class Member {
    private String name;
    private int today_date;


    public Member() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public int getToday_date() {
        return today_date;
    }

    public void setToday_date(int today_date) {
        this.today_date = today_date;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You already got the choosen date inside the `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`. Just declare a global variable and set it inside the listener and then use it when you send your data to `firebase`.

```
String myDate; // a global variable

...

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;
            String date = makeDateString (day, month, year);
            dateButton.setText(date);
            myDate = date; // this is where you initialize yor variable
        }
    };

 ...

 // sending to Firebase:
 btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // you also need to make sure that myDate has a value...

            int date = Integer.parseInt(myDate.trim()); // change here

            member.setToday_date(date);
            member.setName(firstname.getText().toString().trim());
            reff.child(String.valueOf(maxid+1)).setValue(member);
            firstname.getText().clear();
            todays_date.getText().clear();


            }
    });
```